# Android app to tell me how often I turn on the screen per day?

Tags: android

Is there an Android app to tell me how often I turn on the screen per day?

Not the "screen on" duration, but how many times I actually turn the phone on and off.

Requirements:

- Works on Android Lollipop

Comment: If you find none, you can build your own with e.g. Tasker. It can react on the "Display on" event, so you could have a variable holding the counter and write that to a file named YYYYMMDD.txt (e.g. 20150521.txt). With a second rule, reset the counter variable at midnight for a fresh start.

Answer (score 3):

Reporting the number of times the screen is activated is one of the features of the [Quality Time](http://qualitytimeapp.com/) app.

This app tracks your phone usage and provides a number of reports.  It also works with [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com/) to enable you to set daily limits.

Answer (score 1):

I use this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dhgg.appusagemonitor

It counts how often you check your phone per day. And it counts the time you spend on each app.

I use it for my son to show him how much time he spends/wastes on his phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
// INITIALIZE RECEIVER
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    // YOUR CODE
```

This is broad cast receiver you can write your logic code in this class

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // THANKS JASON
    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
            wasScreenOn = false;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // AND DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
// your logic code write here 

            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not a software recommandation...